# It is possible to call an specific builder within a build step?

Tags: buildbot

I have a builder which execute a sequence of steps to install a package.
What I want to do is have another builder in which one of its steps execute all the steps of the previous builder. Is that possible? Execute a builder inside another one?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#triggerable-scheduler

There is a nice little example there.

I would suggest writing a function that defines the package step, something like this:

```
def packageSteps():
    steps=[]
    steps.append(step1)
    steps.append(step2)
    return steps
```

and then add this in all the factories that require packaging

```
f=factory.BuildFactory()
f.addStep(buildstep1)
f.addSteps(packageSteps())
```